# Similar Method call that returns lists

Tags: java, methods, nullpointerexception, google-qpx-express-api

So i have some working code that allows me to generate a list of value to be formatted later in the program. it returns a generic List and Its leading to an API from google (QPX Express) but i don't think this matters for the question.

```
List<TripOption> tripOption = dataFromGoogle() //returns List
```

I was reading over the documentation and it seems that I can use this same API for other values in different Lists. So essentially I would like to use the same call to the API but i can only return one type of list.

```
dataFromGoogle(tripOption, cityData); //gives me null pointer exception
```

So my question would be either what would be a good way to reuse my method to grab different aspects of the API, or ELI5 what causes nullpointers because I always get them and I'm not sure I completely understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exceptions are thrown when you have something like this:

```
Object temp = null;
temp.callMethod();
```

As the name suggests, the NullPointerException occurs when you have a variable that "points" at a null value and try to access something within it as if it were an object.

What's happening with yours probably has something to do with `dataFromGoogle` returning null, and then `dataFromGoogle` attempts to treat it as an object.

Comment: Yes i think I understand it now. Now my problem lies with re factoring. Basically it works when the variable is global but not when passed thru the method...

Comment: Are you talking about using the method `dataFromGoogle` for both getting and updating? If so, read through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html. Specifically the "Overloading Methods" section.

Comment: No... basically i have different List types with QPX but they can all be populated with the same method. So i should be able to use the same method instead of making multiple copies of a method that returns slightly different Lists